# How to turn off the light from particle settings?

Tags: particles, emission

I have a Particle setting to simulate moths following a light bulb. However, i notice that the Cube that i have the Particle settings on emits light, and that the moths themselves emit light as well. How do I change the light settings? I would prefer to turn off the light that comes from the moths so i can have only one light source, which is the lamp.

Here is my file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/h8dzaff312olmrb/Moths.blend/file

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the light in the Moths collection. The particle emitter is duplicating the insects but also the light inside the "moths collections".

Comment: I see, i fixed that, but for some reason, when I hit render, nothing shows up now, even though i have another light source. When i render animation, the video just fades to black, and i can barely see anything else. What happened? My other files can render fine.